# Removing a layout with the click of a button

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to remove a layout with the click of a button.

I have this method in my MainActivity.java file:

```
public void goBack(View view) {
    TableLayout parent = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
    RelativeLayout child = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_displayMessage);
    parent.removeView(child);
}
```

It is fired when this button is clicked in the view I want to remove:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_removeView"
    android:onClick="goBack" />
```

But it gives me this message:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method goBack(View) in
>   a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick

But MainActivity is my main file for all my methods, so I'm not sure why it can't find it.

Where should I put it so that it can be found?

Thanks!

Comment: possible that you are using it in fragment , it won't work with fragment , for simplicity , use `setOnClickListener`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid such problems remove onClick from Layout and instead of that add `OnClickListener` programmically.

First add id to element

```
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/button_removeView"
android:id="@+id/button"
/>
```

Second add listener

```
getView().findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
  //here Your code
  }
});
```

---

In case of using fragment best place will be `onCreateView` method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

    v.findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
        //here Your code
      }
    });

    return v;
}
```

You can also set fragment as listener like:

```
 v.findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(this);
```

and in this case fragement must implement `OnClickListener` interface.

Comment: Shouldn't he remove `android:onClick="goBack" `, too?

Comment: @DaleWilson I mentioned about it in first line "remove onClick from Layout "

Comment: Yes but your example code "add Id to element" still includes it

Answer (score 1):

Use parent.removeViewAt(0) where '0' is the index of the child . It removes the view at particular index .